# Is it possible to find the angles of a quadrilateral given the sides?

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

In the case of a triangle, it is relatively easy to find the three internal angles given the lengths of the three sides by applying the cosine rule. Is it similarly possible to find the angles of a simple (non-self-intersecting) quadrilateral given the lengths of the four sides?

Sub-questions:

1. Are there possibly multiple solutions to a given set of parameters in this case?
2. If it is not possible to solve *in general*, is it at least possible to solve the problem given the constraint that the quadrilateral is convex?
3. *How* to determine the solution(s)?

Thank you!

Comment: No, imagine a picture frame with loose corners that can pivot.  You can stretch it and change it freely.  Only a triangle is defined by all of its side lengths.

Comment: As mentioned (in both the comment and the answer), the answer is no. It would be interesting (like your sub-question #2) to ask what  other minimum additional constraint (if requiring the quadrilateral to be convex does not work) is needed to force the suggested given to work.